# What's wrong with my factory?

Tags: java, factory-pattern

I've got some code like this:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public static Foo getFoo() {
        return new FooImpl();
    }

    abstract void DoFoo();

    private class FooImpl extends Foo {
        public FooImpl() { }

        @Override
        void DoFoo() { }
    }
}
```

But Eclipse is telling me `No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible.` So how can I get this to work?

I attempted to make it as simple as possible to see if it would compile:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public static Foo getFoo() {
        return new FooImpl();
    }

    private static class FooImpl extends Foo {
        public FooImpl() { }
    }
}
```

And I still get the same error. What am I missing?

FIXED! I changed the line `return new FooImpl();` to `return new Foo.FooImpl();`

Comment: public Foo getFoo() should be public static Foo getFoo().

Guessing a typo as the error only occurs and makes sense it getFoo is static.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Excellent explanation [here](http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryInner.jsp) -- in brief, you need to make class `FooImpl` `static`, so it's only tied to the outer class, not to a specific *instance* of the outer class (which you don't have).  The `getFoo` method also looks like it should be static, btw -- otherwise, what *instance* of `Foo` were you planning on calling it on?

Comment: I'm going to be using this in a connection factory. Basically the consumer of the package should never know the concrete class that implements the connection they ask for. Thus there will be `connect()`, `disconnect()` and so-on methods that will be abstract on the Connection class and each implementation is responsible for providing a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 2):

How do you intend people to call `getFoo()`?

Unless you're doing something completely funky and radical, you'll need to make it `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `FooImpl` class `static` and it will work.